# Defining a matrix in Magma with finite field entries

Tags: linear-algebra, magma-cas

Consider the following matrix 
$$
 G:=\left[ 
\begin {array}{cccccccc} 
1&0&0&0&\alpha&\alpha+1&1&1\\ 
0&1&0&0&1&\alpha&\alpha+1&1\\
 0&0&1&0&1&1&\alpha&\alpha+1\\ 
0&0&0&1&\alpha+1&1&1&
\alpha\end {array} 
\right]
$$

where entries of matrix $G$ come from finite field $GF(2^8)$ such that this finite field is constructed by the polynomial ${\alpha}^{8}+{\alpha}^{4}+{\alpha}^{3}+\alpha+1$.

**My question:** How to define matrix $G$ in the [MAGMA](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/) software such that we can see the coding parameters  that are generated with the matrix $G$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At First, we should define the finite field $GF(2^8)$ by our polynomial as follows

$$
K<x>:=ExtensionField< GF(2), z | z^8+z^4+z^3+z+1 >;
$$

After that we have to define matrix space over the finite field $K$, in the following form

$$
M := KMatrixSpace(K, 4, 8);
$$
Now, we define our matrix as shown

$$
G := M ! [1,0,0,0,x,x+1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,x,x+1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,x,x+1,0,0,0,1,x+1,1,1,x];
$$

In continue, we find coding parametr of $G$, by this command

$$
C := LinearCode(G);
$$

I asked two questions about math software in the Math stack. The first question was about Maple that no one answer and because of this I asked from support team of Maple. The next question that you can see was about Magma that again no one answer and I read two chapters of Magma guide to find it's method.

I strongly believed that Math software tags of math stack should be independent of math stack and it's better that defined a separate forum for this special tags.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Please read [this post](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26517/stack-exchange-and-or-mapleprimes) to find out what I mean. Thanks for comment.

Comment: Also the online materials for Magma are quite good with the handbook http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/ as well as a long text called solving problems with magma on the same page. I am glad you found the answer to your question, I didn't have time to write an answer.

Comment: @kodlu I am really glad too that you made comment on my question.   when I read your answers in the Crypto forum, I enjoy it. Thanks for your comment.